# Problem with useDisclouse() in Chakra UI in a forEach loop

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

How can I use useDisclouse() in Chakra with a button in a forEach loop. When I clicked on onClick event a Button it trigger all Buttons.

```js
 const {isOpen:isOpenEdit,onOpen:onOpenEdit,onClose:onCloseEdit} = useDisclosure();
          ...
          return (<Tbody>
            {!isLoading &&
              data.data?.map((row,i) => (
                <Tr ref={rows.current[i]=createRef()} key={i}>
                  <Td>{`$${row.price}`}</Td>
                  <Td maxW={"10em"} overflow={"hidden"}>
                    {row.title}
                  </Td>
                  <Td maxW={"10em"} overflow={"hidden"}>
                    {row.description}
                  </Td>
                  <Td>{row.brand}</Td>
                  <Td maxW={"10em"} overflow={"hidden"}>{Date(row.date).toString()}</Td>
                  <Td>{row.location}</Td>
                  <Td>
                    {row.photo}
                  </Td>
                  <Td>{row.phones?.toString()}</Td>
                  <Td>
                    <ButtonGroup isAttached>
                      <Button key={row.id} onClick={()=>onOpenEdit()} >Edit</Button>
                      <EditModal key={i} isOpen={isOpenEdit} onClose={onCloseEdit} id={row.id}/>
                    </ButtonGroup>
                  </Td>
                </Tr>
              ))}
          </Tbody>)
```

Answer (score 0):

`useDisclosure` only allows you to keep track of one **boolean** value. So for this we need to build something ourselfs.

First we need a state to keep track of the opened modals.

```js
const [isOpenEdits, setIsOpenEdits] = useState({});
```

Now we need a function which helps us to set the state based on the **id** of the row.

```js
const toggleIsOpen = (id, isOpen) => {
  setIsOpenEdits((prevState) => {
    return {
      ...prevState,
      [id]: isOpen,
    };
  });
};
```

We can use this `toggleIsOpen` function in the `ButtonGroup` component and set the `isOpen` prop to the value of `isOpenEdits[row.id]` defaulting to false.

```js
<ButtonGroup isAttached>
  <Button key={row.id} onClick={() => toggleIsOpen(row.id, true)}>
    Edit
  </Button>
  <EditModal
    key={i}
    isOpen={isOpenEdits[row.id] ?? false}
    onClose={() => toggleIsOpen(row.id, false)}
    id={row.id}
  />
</ButtonGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider making modal outside of the forEach loop, have a structure smth like this

```
const {isOpen:isOpenEdit,onOpen:onOpenEdit,onClose:onCloseEdit} = useDisclosure();
const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null)

const handleEdit = (id) => {
   setSelectedId(id)
   onOpenEdit()
}
          ...
          return (<Tbody>
            {!isLoading &&
              data.data?.map((row,i) => (
                <Tr ref={rows.current[i]=createRef()} key={i}>
                  <Td>{`$${row.price}`}</Td>
                  <Td maxW={"10em"} overflow={"hidden"}>
                    {row.title}
                  </Td>
                  <Td maxW={"10em"} overflow={"hidden"}>
                    {row.description}
                  </Td>
                  <Td>{row.brand}</Td>
                  <Td maxW={"10em"} overflow={"hidden"}>{Date(row.date).toString()}</Td>
                  <Td>{row.location}</Td>
                  <Td>
                    {row.photo}
                  </Td>
                  <Td>{row.phones?.toString()}</Td>
                  <Td>
                    <ButtonGroup isAttached>
                      <Button key={row.id} onClick={()=>handleEdit(row.id)} >Edit</Button>
                     
                    </ButtonGroup>
                  </Td>
                </Tr>
              ))}
          </Tbody>)
```

Have a separate made edit modal with id from state.

```
 <EditModal isOpen={isOpenEdit} onClose={onCloseEdit} id={selectedId}/>
```